# Swift Compiler Error: "Type 'Watermark' does not conform to protocol 'ViewModifier'"

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, viewmodifier

I want to add a ViewModifier, as explained in the following tutorial by Paul Hudson (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/custom-modifiers).
My ViewModifier is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Watermark: ViewModifier {
    var text: String

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            content
            Text(text)
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(5)
                .background(Color.black)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func watermarked(with text: String) -> some View {
        self.modifier(Watermark(text: text))
    }
}
```

But I get the following Errors:

[image]

I tried to reproduce this in another project, but there it just works as expected. I tried already cleaning the build folder, remove the derived data, restart Xcode, restart the Mac.

Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I experienced this error before and as what @Asperi said it is naming conflict issue. There may have another entity also named `Content` in the project.

And images for reference:

- [The correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyTvC.png)
- [If there is another class also name Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQ1cO.png)

Comment: You're right! I used the name `Content` twice in the Project. Thanks @AlezPG!

Comment: If you like, you can fix the error without renaming anything by using `SwiftUI.Content` to clarify which `Content` you mean in the code above. It's sometimes annoying that SwiftUI coopted so many "plain" names with no visible namespacing

Comment: Self.Content is what fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

I think you have name conflict, ie. there is another entity named `Watermark` in your project (or visible from other parts), so try to make this modifier unique. Like

```
struct WatermarkModifier: ViewModifier {
 // .. other code
}

extension View {
    func watermarked(with text: String) -> some View {
        self.modifier(WatermarkModifier(text: text))
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that generate an Invalid redeclaration error?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, for some reason not always - I've already met such kind of errors. Also this *I tried to reproduce this in another project, but there it just works as expected* in PO question makes me thinking that it is it.

Comment: I renamed it, and it still give me the sam errors. Thanks anyway for your response.

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann, can you give somehow access to your project?

Comment: It's not an public project and it's supposed to be private.

Comment: The Problem was not that I used `Watermark` twice in the project I used `Content` twice in the Project. as @AlezPG mentioned in his answer.